# Ruby gem referencing different versions of same gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

One of my ruby engine( a gem) is having a dependency on one of my other projects. With some issue in other project I have to uplift the dependency version of a gem in my engine. I am getting the following output when running bundle install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "Gem A":
  In Gemfile:
    My Gem Engine (>= 0) ruby depends on
      Gem A (~> 2.8) ruby

    MyGem Engine (>= 0) ruby depends on
      Gem A (3.0.0.SNAPSHOT.20141016054448)
```

Comment: That means you need to either upgrade Ruby version or downgrade the gem in question.

Comment: my main concern is why does my engine looking for two different versions?

Comment: Change the gem version in your engine's Gemfile then, it may have happened that your engine's Gemfile is pointing to an incompatible version of Gem for the Ruby version you're running.

Comment: well that worked after after updating ruby and rails versions. +1

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the rails and ruby version fixed the issue. The dependent gem is having dependency of latest ruby and rails versions.